# To select max date and time

Tags: sql

I have data with column `createdate` like '24/04/2019 14:52:38',24/04/2019 14:52:37,24/04/2019 14:52:35,24/03/2019 14:52:38 etc.

how to get data based on max date and time in SQL query.

Comment: Have you tried writing a query yet?

Comment: `MAX(createdate)` should return you data based on max date provided datatype of the column createdate is `datetime`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

something like this? (works if `createdate` column is of date/datetime/timestamp type)

```
select
    *
from
    <table_name>
where
    createdate = (select
                      max(createdate)
                  from
                      <table_name>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    top(1) *
from
    xx
order by
    createdate desc
```